# What settings/permissions are required to grant IAM user ssh access to opswork instance?

Tags: ssh, opsworks

In opsworks I have imported the user and marked them to have ssh/rdp access. However, I am unable to ssh into the instance once it is up as that user. And when I access the instance as the root user it doesn't look like the user has been setup. Are there settings in IAM that I am possible missing?

Comment: IAM handles access to various AWS resources. SSH is a resource within your server, so the user's credentials will need to be deployed there. You'll need to refer to OpsWorks documentation to see if there is something specific you need to do to make this happen.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have read the docs, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-ssh-access.html, and all it mentions is adding a public key to an IAM user, importing that user into opswork, and checking ssh/rdp under permissions for the stack. All of which I have done.

Comment: IAM users are not ssh users, cloud-init handles only adding one key to AWS instance at boot time, you need to import any others manually.

Comment: So am I misunderstanding this part of the docs I linked above?  "When you set user permissions for a stack, you specify which users should have SSH access to the stack's instances. AWS OpsWorks automatically creates a system user on the stack's instances for each authorized user and installs their public key. The user can then use the corresponding private key to log in, as described in Logging In with SSH."